# Python Pandas - level exceeded % of time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, statistics, python-xarray

I'm looking for a quick way to calculate a statistical value exceeded % of the time in a 3D matrix. I was looking at using python and pandas but as a newbie I can get my data using xarray in but can't figure out how to perform the statical analysis in the 3D array.

The 3D array is large but for simplicity let just make it a 5x5x5 (s,x,y) array with values between 0 and 99 for each x,y while s is time.

I need to calculate what number was exceeded for each value v in every x,y position through time s. My old school thinking would be to create a new matrix x,y,b then bin (frequency count) each positional x,y value for every second, sort it, then use a percentage to calculate the value exceeded for any v value for every x,y position. (I sure hope that made sense)

So my question.. what is the best/easiest way to accomplish using panadas, xframe, a panel, polars, or other using vectorization?

I suspect vectorization is the best approach (but not well versed in this) or maybe this concept is already baked in.

```
[s1[04,44,71,98,22
    45,13,34,02,69 
    95,82,07,62,83
    52,37,99,01,47
    13,11,64,52,29]
 s2[44,44,71,98,22
    45,13,34,02,69 
    95,82,07,62,83
    52,37,99,01,47
    13,11,64,52,29]
 s3[61,44,71,98,22
    45,13,34,02,69 
    95,82,07,62,83
    52,37,99,01,47
    13,11,64,52,29]
 s4[22,44,71,98,22
    45,13,34,02,69 
    95,82,07,62,83
    52,37,99,01,47
    13,11,64,52,29]
 s5[99,44,71,98,22
    45,13,34,02,69 
    95,82,07,62,83
    52,37,99,01,47
    13,11,64,52,29]
]
```

I haven't tried anything as of yet but looking for the best approach to solving this problem.

Your ideas and examples would be very helpful.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible python object, i.e. complete code that runs and produce an object that we can use. Also provide the matching expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have some data distributed in time and 2 spatial dimensions. For each slice in time, you want the percentage of values that exceed some given limit.

Numpy already vectorizes operations like a simple comparison

```py
import numpy as np

# Generate some random data, 10 time steps, 4 x values, 5 y values.
# Intentionally keeping different sizes for testing as it means it easier to see get the code right.
data = np.random.rand(10, 4, 5)

limit = 0.5

overshoots = data > limit  # 10x4x5 boolean values

r = np.mean(overshoots, axis=(1,2))  # will sum over x and y axis (axis 0 is time)
```

The result `r`  will contain 10 values corresponding to the fraction of times the data overshot the limit. In my test I got:

```py
array([0.6 , 0.55, 0.7 , 0.35, 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.45, 0.65, 0.5 , 0.3 ])
```

Or maybe you wanted the percentage over time? I'm a bit hazy on what you actually want. This would be equally straight forward:

```py
r = np.mean(data > limit, axis=0)  # 4x5 values
```

Comment: x, y are positional that contain a value.  I want to calculate a percentage for each x,y positional value over time. So for the frame above, I want to percentage for 0,0 which be be slice through time [04, 44. 61, 22, 99]

So in your example can you specify a 3rd axis in the entire frame? (If so, that's pretty cool - I'm guess I'm old school and would typically run loops which I know are outdated for this type of analysis.  Still trying to learn though).

Comment: Let me put together real data with expected result.

Comment: It's not a "frame", i just 3D numpy arrays. You can of course choose whichever axis you want. The second variant applies it along the time axis in my example.